# How do I disable the blue circle after each click on Windows Vista TouchSmart?

Tags: windows-vista, touch

Every time I click (by touching the screen) on my HP TouchSmart with Windows Vista, it registers the click by showing a small blue circle where I clicked. This is interfering with a kiosk application I'm developing on it. Does anyone know how I can disable this?